# True or False: $ \| x-y \|_2 \geq | \|x \|_2 - \|y \|_2 |$.

Tags: linear-algebra

True or False: If $x,y \in \mathbb{R^n}$, then$ \| x-y \|_2 \geq | \|x \|_2 - \|y \|_2  |$. Briefly explain why.

Is this statement true by the triangle inequality?

I also know that: $ \| x-y \|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{(x_i-y_i)^2}}$ but not sure if this is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for any norm.
$$\|x\|=\|x-y+y\|\leq\|x-y\|+\|y\|\implies\|x\|-\|y\|\leq\|x-y\|,$$
and
$$\|y\|=\|y-x+x\|\leq\|x-y\|+\|x\|\implies\|y\|-\|x\|\leq\|x-y\|.$$
Thus $-\|x-y\|\leq\|x\|-\|y\|\leq\|x-y\|$, and the result follows.